# Cast a SQL Server REAL to a FLOAT (53) without error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, precision

When transferring data from one database schema to another I encountered a confusing error in casting a `REAL` or `FLOAT(24)` to a `FLOAT(53)`. Both databases are running SQL Server 2017 on Linux.

For example when data such as `33.15` or `96.69` is stored in a column of type `REAL` it is extracted correctly with the following:

```
SELECT [Value] 
FROM MyTable
```

However the following introduces small errors:

```
SELECT CAST([Value] as FLOAT(53)) 
FROM MyTable
```

It returns `33.1500015258789` and `90.6900024414062`.

I understand that most numbers cannot be represented exactly by floating point numbers, but this is transferring from one a 32 bit floating point to a 64 bit floating point.

What causes a the value to change when converting from a smaller approximate SQL Server datatype to a larger approximate datatype? Does it have to do with the required storage size being 4 bytes for a `real` or `float(24)`, but 8 bytes for a `float(53)`?

Comment: Thanks! It threw me off for a bit that the 32 bit float was represented with 4 digits even though 32 bit floats have at least 6 digits. Now I realize that the remaining digits were simply zeros as the difference in the intended value and the stored value was so small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no error.

`33.15` cannot be represented exactly as 32bit float. So what you are seeing is it's more precise representation when there is more precision available.